Taking too long for responding over XML
I am trying to make this request to tally:
<ENVELOPE Action="">
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>COLLECTION</TYPE>
        <ID>CustomVoucherCollection</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
                <EXPLODEFLAG>Yes</EXPLODEFLAG>
                <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Daffoworth Pharmaceutical Pvt. Ltd - (from 1-Apr-2018)</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
                <SVFROMDATE TYPE="Date">01-Apr-2018</SVFROMDATE>
                <SVTODATE TYPE="Date">05-Apr-2018</SVTODATE>
            </STATICVARIABLES>
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="CustomVoucherCollection">
                        <TYPE>Vouchers</TYPE>
                        <NATIVEMETHOD>DATE, EFFECTIVEDATE, GUID, NARRATION, PARTYNAME, PARTYLEDGERNAME, BASICBUYERNAME, VOUCHERNUMBER, VOUCHERNUMBERSERIES, VOUCHERTYPENAME, VOUCHERKEY, ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE, ledgerentries.*, inventoryentries.*</NATIVEMETHOD>
                    </COLLECTION>
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>

But the response is taking too long. Here's everything I have done:

Changed date format to ddmmyyy, yyyymmdd and dd-month-yyyy but there is no difference.
My period on tally is set from 1-Apr-2018 to 1-Apr-2024. If it is set to 2018 FY, the response is as fast as possible, but I want to import data from all FY between the five financial fears.
When I set the period to FY2018, no matter what from date and to date I write, I get the same number of vouchers returned, and it is same if I set from date and to date in Tally as 1-Apr-2018 and 1-Apr-2024

I want to fetch all vouchers between two financial years in batch wise format where if I set to date to 14-Apr-2018 and 15-Apr-2022, I want only those vouchers between the two dates. Nothing else.

if you are in educational mode date filters will not work as expected
